# Odoo 10 - After creating database , logging in = blank page

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I've installed Odoo 10 on Windows 10. Two weeks everything was fine and working.

NOW when I created database and logged in successfully it lead to a blank page.
No thing displayed, just blank page ! I can create databases, and login OK, but I after login a blank page, no apps or services. uploaded image of problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqCnP.jpg

what's the mistake ?

I tried deleted cookies.
I tried restart the postgresql.
I tried uninstall and reinstall.

All not fix the problem

Please help

Regards, ^_^

Comment: first time did you create a database and every thing was good?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Did you change anything in the config file

Comment: No I did not, we are students in UNI we just work in simple things in Sales and Purchase Management

Comment: try to remove ir.attachment

by query: delete from  ir_attachment

Comment: how I remove it :o

Comment: Maybe this is the problem because last thing I have done is uploading a picture for the company logo, but how I delete ir_attachment?

Comment: you can remove its usig rpc or directly run query in database

Answer (score 0):

blank screen after login means you go to ir_attachments table of your odoo database, find all the entry with value 'web/content' in column name and delete them, odoo will regenerate them and voila, you got your odoo back